# Populating Listview from 2 tables

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have 2 tables: `tblstudentbasicinfo` and `tblzipcode`.

- `tblstudentbasicinfo` has the columns

  - `TagID`,
  - `Surname`,
  - `Firstname`,
  - `Middlename`,
  - `Course`,
  - `Year`,
  - `District`,
  - `ZipCode` and
  - `ContacactNo`
- and `tblzipcode` has the columns

  - `ZipCode`,
  - `Province`,
  - `Municipality` and
  - `District`

When a student is entering info, the user can type the district name and the zipcode for that district shown automatically based on what is in the `tblzipcode`.

My problem is when i try populating the listview to show the student basic info with the columns

- `TagID`,
- `Surname`,
- `Firstname`,
- `Middlename`,
- `Course`,
- `Year`,
- `ZipCode`,
- `Province`,
- `Municipality`,
- `District` and
- `ContactNo`

the data wont show.

Here is the sql query that i tried:

```
Dim sql As String = "Select TagID,Surname,Firstname,Middlename,Course,Year,ZipCode,Province,Municipality,District,Contactno from tblstudentbasicinfo AS t1 Inner Join tblzipcode AS t2 On t1.ZipCode = t2.ZipCode and t1.District = t2.District"
```

But i get the error:

> Column 'Zipcode' in the field list is ambiguous.

im new to sql and vb. Can someone tell me how do i fix this? Thank you in advance

Here is my Code on vb:

```
Private Sub Populatelstbasicinfo(TagID As String, Surname As String, Firstname As String, Middlename As String, Course As String, Year As String, ZipCode As String, Province As String, Municipality As String, District As String, contactno As String)
Dim row As String() = New String() {TagID, Surname, Firstname, Middlename, Course, Year, ZipCode, Province, Municipality, District, contactno}


lstbasicinfo.Items.Add(item)
End Sub

Private Sub Retrieve()


    lstbasicinfo.Items.Clear()
    Dim sql As String = "Select TagID,Surname,Firstname,Middlename,Course,Year,t1.ZipCode,Province,Municipality,t2.Barangay,Contactno from tblstudentbasicinfo AS t1 Inner Join tblzipcode AS t2 On t1.ZipCode = t2.ZipCode and t1.Barangay = t2.Barangay"
    cmd = New OdbcCommand(sql, con)

    Try

        con.Open()
        adapter = New OdbcDataAdapter(cmd)
        adapter.Fill(dt)

        For Each row In dt.Rows
            Populatelstbasicinfo(row(0), row(1), row(2), row(3), row(4), row(5), row(6), row(7), row(8), row(9), row(10), row(11), row(12), row(13), row(14), row(15), row(16))
        Next

        con.Close()
        dt.Rows.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: In the select field's list change ZipCode to t1.ZipCode. In this way there is no mistake on which ZipCode should be used to populate the Select list

Comment: Thanks sir, there's no error now but the data still doesn't show. Is my query not the correct way to show the data of the students and their address from two tables?

Comment: No the query is technically correct. Of course it could not return anything because there is no valid join between the two tables using the same ZipCode and District. You could try the query on the administrative tool for your Database system. Other options are caused by your code after this point but we cannot see it. Did you execute the query? Did you use the result (table, reader, dataset) to set the DataSource property of your UI interface widget? You need to add more information relative to your current code.

Comment: I added the code I used in retrieving and populating the listview

Comment: What are you doing in that _Populatelstbasicinfo_? If you are just adding rows to a DataGridView then you should simply set the DataGridView.DataSource property to your DataTable.

Comment: I am using listview. I get an error in my Visual Studio 2010 whenever i try to add data objects such as tables in my database in datasource.

Comment: Perhaps you should try to use the debugger to check if you really get some data back from the query and look at what happens when you add the row to your listview

Answer (score 0):

You should learn good practices when writing queries.  So, consider this:

```
Select bi.TagID, bi.Surname, bi.Firstname, bi.Middlename, bi.Course, bi.Year,
       z.ZipCode, z.Province, z.Municipality, z.District, bi.Contactno
from tblstudentbasicinfo bi Inner Join
     tblzipcode z
     on bi.ZipCode = z.ZipCode and bi.District = z.District;
```

Notes:

- All columns are qualified so you know what tables they come from.
- The tables are given aliases, so the query is easier to write and to read.
- Basic readability is enhanced with spaces and consistent capitalization.

Comment: What about schema on the tables you're accessing? What if the tables are in two different schema's?